# Can two classes be assigned to one enumerator in UML Class diagram

Tags: class, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I am making an UML Class diagram, and got a question on which i could not find an answer.
So the situation is-
I have a class for employee and a class for the client. Both need their name added. Can I use one enumerator called "Name" for both classes, or I need to make an separate enumerator for each class with different naming?

For example-
One enumerator for both classes-
[image]

Or two enumerators- one for each class
[image]

Comment: I don't think you really understand the purpose of enumerations. They are supposed to be a limited list of fixed values. Think colors names, document types, currency codes, etc.... There is no point in having a fixed list of employee names. You wouldn't use a dropdown to choose a name for an employee would you?

Comment: You can do that. But Geert made the point.

Comment: Ok, I got your point @GeertBellekens, but if it is necessary for other purpose, for example, a list for fixed values which is shared between two classes? Do I need an separate enum for each class or one for both?

Comment: No, there is no reason why two classes can't use the same enum.

Comment: There's the same question here (with that same answer). But I can't find it at the moment.